# Json Array Parsing issue

Tags: java, json

``I am having an Json Array as response like:

```
    [
        {
            "status": "Active",
            "entityName": "fghgfhfghfgh",
            "entityCode": 14,
            "children": [],
            "attributes": [
                {
                    "attributeValue": "500 michigan ave"
                }
            ],
            "deviceList": [],
            "entityId": "64eab9299eed9455b3683da074cf175c",
            "customerId": 2006546,
            "type": "7dad308f82b41e02fe8959c05b631bd7"
        }
,
        {
            "status": "Active",
            "entityName": "ghghhguyutgh6re58rrt",
            "entityCode": 13,
            "children": [],
            "attributes": [
                {
                    "attributeValue": "500 michigan ave"
                }
            ],
            "deviceList": [],
            "entityId": "912eff0613fa140c100af435c033e195",
            "customerId": 2006546,
            "type": "7dad308f82b41e02fe8959c05b631bd7"
        }
    ]
```

I want to split this json into two like

> {
>       "status": "Active",
>       "entityName": "fghgfhfghfgh",
>       "entityCode": 14,
>       "children": [],
>       "attributes": [
>           {
>               "attributeValue": "500 michigan ave"
>           }
>       ],
>       "deviceList": [],
>       "entityId": "64eab9299eed9455b3683da074cf175c",
>       "customerId": 2006546,
>       "type": "7dad308f82b41e02fe8959c05b631bd7" }

and the other one.I am using GSON and simplejson,when I try to remove the delimiters([ and ])the json comes as malformed one.Is there any better otpion to split the json array to two or more json strings as per the json response coming.

Comment: Why do you want to do something like that? The main purpose of an array is to contain multiple elements

Comment: as the data is coming as array from db(cassandra),i want to extract and expose the data to some other services

Comment: Still I don't understand your main need

Comment: I want to pick some data from json response and form another json and expose the data to fron end,if two json data comes in array I should pick the data from these two jsons and expose it

Comment: Then I guess you can just parse the initial JSON and then manipulate it as you wish, by removing elements or modifying them and then convert the object to json encode...

Comment: @Vik you mean the initial json coming as array?but how to parse them and take whatever we needed?any snippets?

Comment: If you're using Java you could take a look here http://eclipsesource.com/blogs/2013/04/18/minimal-json-parser-for-java/ and then parse the JSON in a java Array. After that, you should know how to manipulate the array and then pack a JSON back. Another useful resource could be https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/

Answer (score 0):

Is there any reason you can't parse the entire array, and then iterate over/process each element individually?

Just removing the brackets does make the JSON invalid, and splitting at the comma is going to be unreliable. The parser exists to figure out where to split the array and turn each element into an object for you.

Assuming you have some data structure defined to hold a single element once you've broken the array down, you should be able to parse the array into a list of those and step through them (or pick one out) as needed.

After that point, you can do whatever you want with the data (including formatting it back into JSON). I would definitely recommend using a proper parser to break the array down, though; it will be a lot simpler and more reliable, and should work unless you have serious performance concerns.